# Getting Error Couldn't load class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am implementing P2PKIT in my `xamarin` `android` project, for that I have done following steps:

- I have created Library project in android studio to enable p2pkit
  and created `JAR` file.
- I have created Binding Library Project in visual studio and added
  created JAR file into Binding Library Project.
- Setting JAR file Build action as EmbededJar.
- Giving Reference of Binding Libarary Project into my
  Xamarin `Android` project

> When running app in visual studio it is crashing and throwing
>   Exception Couldn't load class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ch/uepaa/p2pkit/P2PKitStatusListener

As per my observation, `P2PKitStatusListener` is not accessible in visual studio. How I can access `P2PKitStatusListener` in visual studio project?

Note: I used same JAR file inside android studio application and its working fine.

Comment: Can you run the app again and show me the proper output so, I can see what's up?